# Conditional Compilation not succeeding swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, conditional-compilation

I have two targets in my project **TargetA** and **TargetB**

TargetA bridging header file **TargetA-Bridging-Header.h**

```
#import "Class1.h"
#import "Class2.h"
#import "Class3.h"
```

TargetB bridging header file **TargetB-Bridging-Header.h**

```
#import "Class4.h"
#import "Class5.h"
#import "Class6.h"
```

There is one class of swift that is used in both Targets with name **"MyCombinedTargetsClass.swift"**

It has the following code

```
#if TARGETA
    Class2.instance().someMethod()
#endif
```

Now the problem is if I compile TargetA then it succeeds but If I compile TargetB it gives me error "unresolved identifier Class2" though the code is written under macro of TargetA **#if TARGETA**

Comment: Are your sure your `TARGETA`  define is defined only within target A. I've made a test project at https://www.dropbox.com/s/zvtebzteh70vi5q/testTarget2.zip?dl=0 and it works fine

Comment: @MichaëlAzevedo you were right I was using the wrong flag in case of TARGETB it was TARGETA in "other swift flags" settings

Comment: I thought about it because while doing my test project i did it too ^^ Glad you found it